# Codeigniter Paging with $this->db->query is not working

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-2

```
Url - localhost/ci/test/test_que/1

$sql="
select qo.id,
       qo.text 
FROM quiz_question qq,
quiz_question_option qo 
WHERE qq.id='".$qid."' 
AND qq.id=qo.quiz_question_id";

$q=$this->db->query($sql,$num,$qid);
```

How to implement it? How to set Pagination?

Comment: Maybe the answer is here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html or here: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/ Post back if anything goes wrong..but it should not as the video tutorial is crystal clear.

Comment: What *exactly* isn't working? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function total_rows($sql){
$Query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $Query->num_rows();

}

$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ci/test/test_que/1'; //your base url
$config['uri_segment'] = 3; //set URI Segment
$config['total_rows'] = $this->total_rows($sql); //your sql query for counting rows
$config['per_page'] = 10; //files or questions per page


$this->pagination->initialize($config); //put this in view
```

Thats it